# How to find generating function of a sequence

Tags: generating-functions

Need help to find generating function of the following series.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n+1}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Should $n$ be replaced with $i$?

Comment: It's a dummy index. It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}x^n$

$xG(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}$

$\frac{d}{dx}xG(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{d}{dx}x^{n+1}$

$\frac{d}{dx}xG(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n} = \frac{1}{1-x}$

This implies $G(x) = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{x}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_0^x t^{n} dt = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} 
$$

we then have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n+1} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^x t^n dt = \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x dt \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n
$$
The last sum is the geometric series which has a known closed form for $|t| < 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$=\frac{1}{x}\sum \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}=-\frac{1}{x}\log(1-x)$$