# Closed form of a power series of $f(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0 } \frac{x^n}{n+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Find a closed form (not a sum) of the power series

$$f(x) = \sum^\infty_{n=0 } \frac{x^n}{n+1}$$

which converges on the interval $[-1,1)$ by differentiating the series on its interval of convergence and finding an antiderivative to lead to $f(x)$

Comment: The hint in the question could give you an answer.  What happened when you tried it?  Perhaps looking at  $xf(x)$ might make it even easier

Comment: what have you done? would you like to share your thoughts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find generating function of a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2261093/how-to-find-generating-function-of-a-sequence)

Answer (score 2):

Notice that: $$xf(x)=\sum_{n\ge0}\int x^ndx$$Since this converges, flip the order of the integral and the sigma:$$\sum_{n\ge0}\int x^ndx=\int\sum_{n\ge0} x^ndx$$Use geometric series to get: $$\int\frac{1}{1-x}dx=xf(x)$$$$-\frac{1}{x}\ln(1-x)=f(x)$$Thanks to @Zakhurf for correcting my answer.

Comment: The last part of this answer is wrong. We obtain  $$x f(x) = \int \frac{1}{1-x}dx$$ which can be written as an elemantary function. Indeed $$f(x) = -\frac{1}{x}\ln(1-x)$$ However, the rest of the reasoning is correct.

Comment: @Zakhurf I edited the answer :)